# Guessing Game, loop error

Tags: java, performance

I'm having a problem with the following code for a guessing game, range set for 1-32. It starts up, but once I take my first guess, I'm given either Too High or Too Low,plus the correct answer. So I'm always able to get the correct answer in 2 guesses, which isn't suppose to happen. I think I have a problem with the while loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*
     * Following should create a random number
     * Generated by computer between 0-32
     */
    Random rng = new Random ();
    int value = rng.nextInt(32);
    int numberOfTries = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int guess = 0;
    boolean win = false;
    while (win == false) {


    System.out.println("Guess of a Number between 1-32, I will tell you \n " +
                        "if your guess is too high, too low, or correct!");

        /*
         * Uses makes a guess and program tells if the guess is correct,
         * too high, or too low.
         */

    System.out.println("Enter your guess: ");
    guess = input.nextInt();
    numberOfTries++;

    if (guess == value){
        win = true;

    }   else if (guess > value){
        System.out.println("Your guess is too high, try again");

    } else if (guess < value){
        System.out.println("Your guess is too low, try again");


    }
    System.out.println("Yes, the number is " + value);
    System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tries");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: well, you print the number every time in the loop, because the `System.out.println` isn´t in a condition, like `if(guess==value)`

Comment: @neme0025 How did you do? Have you solved it?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't line up my curly brackets correctly. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please consider voting for/ accepting the answer, if it was helpful to you. Have a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the how and why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
System.out.println("Yes, the number is " + value);
System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tries");
```

into your condition here:

```
if (guess == value){
    win = true;
}
```

Otherwise, it will be called unconditionally - meaning in every iteration of the loop. Alternatively, you can print it after your while loop, as the game is finished there.